# Regex for reverse match a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to reverse match a string using regex

ex: "test.com".match(/gmail.test.com/)(we can do like "gmail.test.com".match(/test.com/) but I have a situation which requires to check inverse match).

Is it possible?. Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does *inverse match* mean? Perhaps some examples would help.

Comment: What is the relation between *reverse match* and *inverse match*? The last thing I would like to think is that this is just the OP's sloppiness/stupidity, but I hope it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> 'gmail.test.com'.split('.').last(2) == ['test','com']
=> true
```